# Flutter: How can I select an image icon in a list without all icons in the list being selected?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I have created a List in Flutter using Sliver (Sliver Structure below):

```
return Scaffold(

  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        //leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        expandedHeight: 150.0,
        pinned: true,
      ),

      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final item = taskList[index];

            return Card()
```

The Card has a Dismissible Widget encapsulated within which creates a ListTile. The Dismissible works fine and I can swipe to dismiss individual cells in the list.

The issue I am having is related to an IconButton in my ListTile. My aim is that whenever I tap the IconButton it should toggle an Icon Flag on or off for the individual cell, but what happens is that all of the Icon Buttons in the List are toggled. From investigating the Dismissible Widget code I can understand that I need to uniquely identify each cell for this to work, I've tried using a Key to make the cells unique but that hasn't worked. Is anybody able to steer me in the right direction? The code for the IconButton is below, I also attempted to add a key to the ListTile but that didn't work so I removed it.

```
IconButton( 
  key: Key(item),
  icon: Icon(Icons.flag),
  color: (isPriority) ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
  onPressed: _toggleFlag,
)
```

Comment: update your _toggleFlag  code?

Comment: Would I need to pass the key into the toggle flag code to pass in the key?    

    void _toggleFlag() {
      setState(() {
        if (isPriority) {
          isPriority = false;
        } else {
          isPriority = true;
        }
    });
  }

Comment: are you using imagebutton inside your listview?

Comment: use _togglrFlag inside set State

Comment: correct, the Image button is inside the Sliver List, the encapsulation is as follows SliverList -> SliverChildBuilderDelegate -> Card -> Dismissible -> ListTile -> IconButton

Comment: below code is working?

Answer (score 0):

Create your card like this

```
 return new Users(example: taskList[index]);
```

then craete  widget for card

```
class Users extends StatefulWidget
{

final String example;
const  Users  ({Key key, this.example}) : super(key: key);
@override
UserWidgets createState() => UserWidgets();
}

class UserWidgets extends State<Users>
{

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context)
 {
     return new Container(

  child: Card(
     child:new IconButton( 
 icon: Icon(Icons.flag),
 color: (isPriority) ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
 onPressed: ()
   {
    setState(() {
  if (isPriority) {
  isPriority = false;
  } else {
  isPriority = true;
  }
  });
   }
    ,
   ), 
  );
  }
```

Comment: no it did not work, it still toggles all of the flags in the list. I want it to only toggle the flag of the cell it belongs to.

Comment: is tasklist file or image or string?

Comment: tasklist is a list of Strings, it can uniquely add the lists to the cells, that part works fine. So I have a cell for each element in the list

Comment: if you want to access anything you can use widget.example like this

Comment: thanks for your response, how will this make the list cells unique to a icon tap compared to the way I did it using the Key. I'm trying to understand why i went wrong in my approach

Answer (score 0):

My toggleFlag code is below, I already have a setState in there, it toggles the flag but the issue is that it toggles all flags in the list when i want to toggle the flag of the cell that it belongs to:

```
void _toggleFlag() {
  setState(() {
    if (isPriority) {
      isPriority = false;
    } else {
      isPriority = true;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to simplify my code to capture all of it and show where the icon button fits in (the icon button is right at the bottom). I'm still getting the issue that if I tap on an icon flag all of the icon flags are then toggled on rather than the specific one that I tapped.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _HomePageDemoState createState() => _HomePageDemoState();
}

class _HomePageDemoState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> taskList = [
    'The Enchanted Nightingale',
    'The Wizard of Oz',
    'The BFG'
  ];
  bool isPriority = false;

  void _toggleFlag() {
    setState(() {
      if (isPriority) {
        isPriority = false;
      } else {
        isPriority = true;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final item = taskList[index];
                return Card(
                  elevation: 8.0,
                  child: ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    leading: Container(
                      color: (isPriority) ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                      //padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '01',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text('$item'), //Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
                    subtitle:
                        Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),


                    trailing: IconButton(
                      key: Key(item),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.flag),
                      color: (isPriority) ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                      onPressed: _toggleFlag,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: taskList.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```